# How to install TWRP after Magisk?

Tags: twrp, magisk, oneplus-6

## How to install TWRP after Magisk?

I have a OnePlus 6 running Oxygen OS 9.0 and I managed to install Magisk by obtaining the stock boot image and using the magisk manager app to patch it to include magisk, then I flashed the patched boot.img using fastboot and ADB.

The reason I did it this way is that every time I tried to boot with twrp.img in order to flash twrp.zip, I would run into a screen saying Qualcomm CrashDump Mode and TWRP wouldn't boot.

Now I want to install TWRP and I was wondering if there is any way of doing it by using Magisk, so I wouldn't have to boot twrp.img.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

**There is different method from Android 9 and later.**

For Android 9 and 10 devices, ensure to disable dm_verity by flashing an empty vbmeta before flashing magisk patched boot. Some devices most especially those using Unisoc chipset require that you generate your custom signed vbmeta.

*Sorry, I don't know more but only this difference about Android 9 or newer.*

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue. The problem is that regular twrp (current version 3.2.3) does not work with Oxygen OS 9.0.

The solution is to use blu_spark twrp, which does work. You can find the download here:

https://forum.xda-developers.com/devdb/project/?id=27466#downloads

(twrp-3.2.3-x_blu_spark_v9.86_op6.img and twrp-3.2.3-x_blu_spark_v9.86_op6.zip)

linked to from the main Oxygen OS 9.0 oneplus 6 thread on xda-developers:

https://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-6/how-to/official-oxygenos-5-1-5-ota-oneplus-6-t3794232